# Colocar las rutas correctas en mi extension Live Server Web Extension

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, extensiones

Buen día , tengo un inconveniente sobre que ruta colocar en el Servidor actual en la extensión Live Server Web Extensión, es para montar un servidor local con PHP sin la necesidad de utilizar Xampp u otro servidor web.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por supuesto instalé también la Extensión PHP Server que es el que me levanta el servidor con PHP pero cuando lo ejecuto me dice: 'PHP not found'
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya configuré mi ruta path dentro del editor, pero no consigo hallar la ruta correcta para colocar en esta extensión para que me permita de una vez por todas levantar el servidor.

Instalé php directo y lo coloque en una carpeta llamada PHP8 y en la misma, una Carpeta de Ejercicios donde tengo mis scripts que son los que quiero levantar (Algo parecido a como es Xampp)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He colocado rutas relativas y absolutas pero no logro nada.

Les dejo el link del repositorio que detalla todo sobre esta extensión (Ojo ya la he leído), pero no logro obtener los resultados.

https://github.com/ritwickdey/live-server-web-extension/blob/master/docs/Setup.md

Comment: según la documentación necesitas un servidor web + procesador de php , segun entiendo lo que hace esta extensión es recargar la pagina cuando grabas el archivo q estas editando

Comment: El detalle está en las rutas que configuro en la extensión qué es lo que me está generando el error. Hace poco logré hacer la configuración correcta de las rutas y funcionaba , pero no las respaldé y volví a lo mismo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se resolvió.

1. Crear los archivos o carpetas que utilizaremos dentro de la carpeta donde está instalado el PHP (Similar a lo que ocurre con el Htdocs de Xampp y el www de WAMP)
2. Cuando se abre el Visual Studio Code , se debe importar toda la carpeta , no solo el archivo donde vamos a trabajar
3. Configuramos el Actual Server Address con nuestra ruta del archivo , o la carpeta y funciona.